# error dart migration tool - Expected a value of type '(UserCredential) => FutureOr<UserCredential>', but got one of type '(dynamic) => Future<Null>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to figure out, how I can get my database request "signUpUser" to work again. Before I used null-safety my code worked fine, but now after using the dart migration tool I am getting the error:

```
Expected a value of type '(UserCredential) => FutureOr<UserCredential>', but got one of type '(dynamic) => Future<Null>'
```

How can I fix this error? I am really desperate, I don't understand this error and I need to   have a working code. If I can't fix this error, then I must use a not null-safety code, so I hope you can help me.

The registration works fine, just the database request is throwing an error.

**Database request:**

```
  Future<bool> signUpUser(String username, String email, String password,
  String firstName, String lastName, String? birthday, String? gender) async {
try {
  _status = Status.Authenticating;
  notifyListeners(); //changing status

  FirebaseApp secondaryApp = await Firebase.initializeApp(
    name: 'Secondary',
    options: Firebase.app().options,
  );

  try {
    UserCredential credential = await FirebaseAuth.instanceFor(
            app: secondaryApp)
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
        .then((result) async {
      //User user = result.user;
      _userServices.createUser(
        uid: result.user!.uid,
        username: username,
        email: email,
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        birthday: birthday,
        gender: gender,
        status: 'aktiv',
        role: 'User',
      );
    }as FutureOr<UserCredential> Function(UserCredential));

    if (credential.user == null) {
      throw 'An error occured. Please try again.';
    }
    await credential.user!.sendEmailVerification();
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
  await secondaryApp.delete();

  return true;
} catch (e) {
  _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
  notifyListeners();
  print(e.toString());
  return false;
}
```

}

**registration:**

```
InkWell(
                            onTap: () async {
                              final Formkey = _formKeys.currentState;

                              print('pw confirmed:' +
                                  passwordConfirmedController.text.trim());
                              print('pw:' + passwordController.text.trim());

                              //password and passworconfirm check
                              if (passwordConfirmedController.text.trim() ==
                                  passwordController.text.trim()) {
                                //checking if all textfields are not empty
                                if (usernameController.text.trim() != null &&
                                    emailController.text.trim() != null &&
                                    passwordController.text.trim() != null &&
                                    passwordConfirmedController.text.trim() !=
                                        null &&
                                    firstNameController.text.trim() != null &&
                                    lastNameController.text.trim() != null &&
                                    isDateSelected != false &&
                                    _genderSelected != null) {
                                  // checking if all textfields are valid
                                  if (Formkey!.validate()) {
                                    print('validate okok');

                                    // input is the authProvider.emailController, which provides the written email
                                    // output are all the user informations in a Map<String, dynamic>
                                    // used to check the status and role of the user
                                    mapUserinformations =
                                        await authProvider.getUserByEmail(
                                            emailController.text.trim());

                                    //when email exist, then check status
                                    if (mapUserinformations!.isNotEmpty) {
                                      print('email is already existing');

                                      mapUsernameExist = await authProvider.UsernameExist(mapUserinformations!['username']);
                                      //if username already exist, then print error otherwise it is free
                                      if (mapUsernameExist!.isEmpty){
                                        print('username is free');

                                      //checking if status is deleted
                                      if (mapUserinformations!['status'] ==
                                          'gelöscht') {
                                        print('email is deleted');

                                        //recreate the deleted user
                                        try {
                                          //update user informations
                                          await authProvider.updateUserSignup(
                                              mapUserinformations!['uid'],
                                              mapUserinformations!['username'],
                                              mapUserinformations!['email'],
                                              mapUserinformations!['firstName'],
                                              mapUserinformations!['lastName'],
                                              _birthDateInString,
                                              _genderSelected,
                                              'User');

                                          //input: emailcontroller, output: send password reset link
                                          try {
                                            await FirebaseAuth.instance
                                                .sendPasswordResetEmail(
                                                    email: emailController.text
                                                        .trim());
                                          } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                                            print(e);
                                            showDialog(
                                                context: context,
                                                builder: (context) {
                                                  return AlertDialog(
                                                    content: Text(
                                                        e.message.toString()),
                                                  );
                                                });
                                          }
                                          clearController();
                                          isDateSelected = false;
                                          _genderSelected = null;

                                          // deleted user got recreated - now print a message that the registration process is completed
                                          showDialog(
                                              context: context,
                                              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                                return AlertDialog(
                                                  title: Text(
                                                      "Registration abgeschlossen.\nDein Account war gelöscht, daher wurde dir eine E-Mail zum zurücksetzen deines persönlichen Passworts zugesendet.\nNachdem du das Passwort abgeändert hast, kannst du "
                                                      "dich nun in unserer App einloggen.",
                                                      textAlign:
                                                          TextAlign.center),
                                                  actions: [
                                                    TextButton(
                                                      child: Text("Ok"),
                                                      onPressed: () {
                                                        Navigator.of(context)
                                                            .pop();
                                                      },
                                                    )
                                                  ],
                                                );
                                              });
                                        } catch (e) {
                                          print(e);
                                        }
                                      }
                                      // email is already existing and the status is not deleted
                                      else {
                                        showDialog(
                                            context: context,
                                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                              return AlertDialog(
                                                title: Text(
                                                    "Error: Es existiert schon ein Account mit dieser E-Mail Adresse."),
                                                actions: [
                                                  TextButton(
                                                    child: Text("Ok"),
                                                    onPressed: () {
                                                      Navigator.of(context)
                                                          .pop();
                                                    },
                                                  )
                                                ],
                                              );
                                            });
                                      }
                                    }else{
                                        showDialog(
                                            context: context,
                                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                              return AlertDialog(
                                                title: Text(
                                                    "Error: Der Username wird bereits verwendet. Bitte benutze einen anderen."),
                                                actions: [
                                                  TextButton(
                                                    child: Text("Ok"),
                                                    onPressed: () {
                                                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                                    },
                                                  )
                                                ],
                                              );
                                            });
                                      }
                                    }
                                    // email not existing in database -> mapUserinformations = null
                                    else {
                                      try {
                                        print('email existiert noch nicht');
                                        // sign up user in database with the birthday and gender + all controllers from authProvider
                                        await authProvider.signUpUser(
                                            usernameController.text.trim(),
                                            emailController.text.trim(),
                                            passwordController.text.trim(),
                                            firstNameController.text.trim(),
                                            lastNameController.text.trim(),
                                            _birthDateInString,
                                            _genderSelected);
                                        clearController();
                                        isDateSelected = false;
                                        _genderSelected = null;

                                        showDialog(
                                            context: context,
                                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                              return AlertDialog(
                                                title: Text(
                                                    "Registration abgeschlossen. Du kannst dich nun in unserer App einloggen."),
                                                actions: [
                                                  TextButton(
                                                    child: Text("Ok"),
                                                    onPressed: () {
                                                      Navigator.of(context)
                                                          .pop();
                                                    },
                                                  )
                                                ],
                                              );
                                            });
                                      } catch (e) {
                                        print(e);
                                      }
                                    }
                                  } else {
                                    print('validate email notgoodatall');
                                    showDialog(
                                        context: context,
                                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                          return AlertDialog(
                                            title: Text(
                                                "Error: Bitte überprüfe, ob alle deine Eingaben ein gültiges Format aufweisen."),
                                            actions: [
                                              TextButton(
                                                child: Text("Ok"),
                                                onPressed: () {
                                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                                },
                                              )
                                            ],
                                          );
                                        });
                                  }
                                }
                                // not all Textfields/Buttons are filled
                                else {
                                  showDialog(
                                      context: context,
                                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                        return AlertDialog(
                                          title: Text(
                                              "Error: Registration gescheitert! Bitte alle Felder ausfüllen."),
                                          actions: [
                                            TextButton(
                                              child: Text("Ok"),
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                              },
                                            )
                                          ],
                                        );
                                      });
                                  return;
                                }
                              } else {
                                showDialog(
                                    context: context,
                                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                      return AlertDialog(
                                        title: Text(
                                            "Error: Passwort und Passwort wiederholen müssen gleich sein!"),
                                        actions: [
                                          TextButton(
                                            child: Text("Ok"),
                                            onPressed: () {
                                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                            },
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      );
                                    });
                              }
                            },
                            child: Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.deepPurple,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                width: double.maxFinite,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                                child: Text(
                                  "Registrieren",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                ))),
```

Comment: Casting a `Function` from one type to another is almost always the wrong thing to do.  The migration tool has some bugs that sometimes cause it to incorrectly cast function types; you should remove the `as FutureOr<UserCredential> Function(UserCredential))` cast, see what fails, and try to fix it another way (usually by correcting the parameter and return types to match).  Unrelated, but it also is bad style to mix `await` and `.then()`.  It's unnecessary and makes your code harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

@jamesdlin Answered my question. The edited database request looks like this:

```
      Future<bool> signUp(
          String username,String email,String password,String firstName,
          String lastName,String? birthday,String? gender,String? role) async {
        try {
          FirebaseApp secondaryApp = await Firebase.initializeApp(
            name: 'Secondary',
            options: Firebase.app().options,
          );
    
          try {
            UserCredential? credential = await FirebaseAuth.instanceFor(
                    app: secondaryApp)
                .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    
            _userServices.createUser(
              uid: await credential.user!.uid,
              username: username,
              email: email,
              firstName: firstName,
              lastName: lastName,
              birthday: birthday,
              gender: gender,
              status: 'aktiv',
              role: role,
            );
    
            if (credential.user == null) {
              throw 'An error occured. Please try again.';
            }
            await credential.user!.sendEmailVerification();
            print('send verfication');
            await secondaryApp.delete();
            print('deleted instance');
          } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
            print(e);
          }
    
          return true;
        } catch (e) {
          print(e.toString());
          return false;
        }
      }
```